# gradle - how does interface org.gradle.api.Action work?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to understand android plugin, when I look at "defaultConfig", I find the method is

```
public void defaultConfig(Action<ProductFlavor> action) {
    this.checkWritability();
    action.execute(this.defaultConfig);
}
```

and calling action.execute(this.defaultConfit) invokes the closure against this.defaultConfig.

This is confusing, so I looked at doc of interface Action to see what magic it has.

According to [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Action.html) of Action interface, when calling action.execute(obj), it actually "Performs this action against the given object", and the given object here is obj.

How does this work?

ASAIK, if I wish to call a method against obj, I use "it" to reference to the obj: `it.doSth()`, otherwise the method will be invoked against "this".

But when using Action interface, "it" is no more necessary and method calls within this interface will just be invoked against "it".

I also write some code to test it:

```
class Main {
        Test test = new Test()
        test.actionReceiver {
//            actionName "test ok"
            it.actionName "test ok"

        }

    }

    static interface MyAction<T> {
        void execute(T)
    }

    static class MyActionReceiver {
        void actionName(String name) {
            println name
        }
    }

    static class Test {
        MyActionReceiver actionReceiver = new MyActionReceiver()

        void actionReceiver(MyAction<MyActionReceiver> action) {
            action.execute(actionReceiver)
        }

    }

}
```

If my interface `MyAction` had the magic that Action interface has, then calling actionName without "it" should just work, however it didn't.

My question is: how Action interface works and how can I make my interface work the same way?

Comment: Looks like you should study the basics of Groovy, particularly how Closures work. Without that knowledge, you will have a very hard time writing code for plugins. See http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html

Answer (score 1):

Gradle tasks can contain one or more Actions. You can find more about Actions here: 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Action.html#execute(T)
Actions are typically defined in the

> doFirst{...}

or

> doLast{...}

block of a task definition. See:

```
task hello {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello world!'
    }
}
```

When writing custom tasks you can simply annotate your main action with the **@TaskAction** annotation:

```
task hello(type: GreetingTask)

class GreetingTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
         println 'hello from GreetingTask'
     }
}
```

Some more helpful links:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html

Comment: Notice that the question is not about tasks at all, but rather about `Action<T>` interface used in authoring Gradle DSL.